# Take various Integer Inputs on same line JAVA

Tags: java, matrix, input, formatting, java.util.scanner

I want to take various `integer` inputs on same line, lets say 2. Actually I want to take input in shape of a *Matrix* as input values will be stored in a form of matrix.

The problem is that I can only take one input per line and it goes to the next line for taking next input. I think its `Scanner.nextInt()` that causes the cursor to got to the next line as I have to press *enter* after giving each input.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Matrix
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = false;
        int row = 2 , col =2;
        int[][] array = new int[row][col];
        do
        {
            System.out.printf("\n>>>>> Enter values for Matrix <<<<<\n");
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.print("\n[  ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) 
                    {
                        array[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("   ");
                    }
                    System.out.print("  ]\n");
                }
                flag = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try Again.");
                String flush = input.next();
                flag = false;
            }
        }while(!flag);      
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Result]

**Desired Output:**

> [  2  3  ]
>
> [  8  4  ]

I have searched this problem on internet but everyone is taking one input per line but I want it to take input in Matrix style.

Comment: you can take input divided by spaces too. they all will be evaluated once you press the enter key

Comment: Sometimes best to get a line of input via `.nextLine()`, and then handle the line either by splitting, or creating a new Scanner based solely on the line of text. `Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(singleLineOfText);`

Comment: I already know this solution, thanks .. but what i want to do is take individual input ! I think its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the input line as a string of numbers separated by spaces then split it

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
{
    System.out.print("\n[  ");
    String matrixRow = input.next();
    String[] numbers = matrixRow.split(" ");
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) 
    {
         array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
     }
     System.out.print("  ]\n");
}
```

Comment: I already know this solution, thanks .. but what i want to do is take individual input ! I think its not possible.

Comment: Did you try to get the input as integers separated by spaces but without using strings? It works with me to take the inputs this way and each input goes to the corresponding variable as specified in the input order